# Построение графика с градиентом

Tags: php

Подскажите реально ли построить график вот такого вида:[image: Графика] 
И если не сложно хотелось бы пример так как у самого мозгов не хватит на это.

> я использую на веб странице highcharts и скрипя зубами доволен. Но мне
>   нужно сделать информер в виде баннера. Картинки png которую будет
>   генерировать PHP. Так как по мимо графики там будет и другая
>   информация в виде текста и других картинок. Так что js тут точно не
>   пойдет.

Comment: есть javascript библиотеки для этого

Comment: @Pavel Bereznichenko я бы это указал, меня интересует именно на PHP

Comment: @wwwplaton как то не могу понять вас, вам просто нужно что бы у клиента был график я правильно понял? на сайте

Comment: @Razmik Galstyan мне как раз нужна именно картинка сгенерированная на PHP.

Comment: @wwwplaton посмотрите мой ответ, а если что то не устраивает то нужно исправить вопрос и дать подробности что бы кто то смог помочь вам.

Comment: @wwwplaton и еще один момент допустим мы можем на `php` сделать картинку, а откуда берутся данные для него?

Comment: @Razmik Galstyan данные для графика из БД я беру, это не столь важно. Самое главное отрисовать графику. Саму картинку создаю так же на php `imagecreatefrompng`

Comment: может это вам поможет? https://phpclub.ru/detail/article/dynamic_image, http://www.softtime.ru/info/articlephp.php?id_article=38, http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=953&rub=37

Comment: @Razmik Galstyan да, таких примеров полно. Но как сделать с градиентом?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727197/can-you-get-a-transparent-gradient-using-php-imagemagick

Comment: @E_p Я так понял на примере GD я не найду?

Comment: @wwwplaton Ну GD работу с альфа каналом поддерживает(http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php). Только я подозреваю своего кода надо будет больше.